# ClassNotFoundException javax.mail.internet.AddressException when running hibernate3:hbm2ddl

Tags: log4j, maven, hbm2ddl

So I'm having trouble with log4j and hbm2ddl.
When I put an SMTPAppender in my log4j.xml I get this ClaasNotFoundException.

Any Hints on how to solve this?

These are my config files and the stacktrace:

stackctrace:

```
        [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building Unnamed - Mail-logging-and-hbm2ddl:Mail-logging-and-hbm2ddl:jar:1.0
    [INFO]    task-segment: [package]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (windows-1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] Copying 3 resources
    [INFO] Copying 2 resources
    [INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
    [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
    [INFO] Preparing hibernate3:hbm2ddl
    [WARNING] Removing: hbm2ddl from forked lifecycle, to prevent recursive invocation.
    [INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (windows-1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] Copying 3 resources
    [INFO] Copying 2 resources
    [INFO] [hibernate3:hbm2ddl {execution: default}]
    [INFO] Configuration XML file loaded: file:/D:/DEV/PROJECTS/Mail%20logging%20and%20hbm2ddl/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml
    [FATAL ERROR] org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.exporter.Hbm2DDLExporterMojo#execute() caused a linkage error (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError) and may be out-of-date. Check the realms:
    [FATAL ERROR] Plugin realm = app0.child-container[org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2]
    urls[0] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/hibernate3-maven-plugin/2.2/hibernate3-maven-plugin-2.2.jar
    urls[1] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.14/log4j-1.2.14.jar
    urls[2] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-tools/3.2.3.GA/hibernate-tools-3.2.3.GA.jar
    urls[3] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar
    urls[4] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.8/freemarker-2.3.8.jar
    urls[5] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/jtidy/r8-20060801/jtidy-r8-20060801.jar
    urls[6] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.1.GA/hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar
    urls[7] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.6/antlr-2.7.6.jar
    urls[8] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.1/commons-collections-3.1.jar
    urls[9] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
    urls[10] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
    urls[11] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.6/slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
    urls[12] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/hibernate3/maven-hibernate3-api/2.2/maven-hibernate3-api-2.2.jar
    urls[13] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
    urls[14] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec/1.1.1/geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec-1.1.1.jar
    urls[15] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.5.6/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar
    urls[16] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.5.6/jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.6.jar
    urls[17] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/hibernate3/maven-hibernate3-jdk14/2.2/maven-hibernate3-jdk14-2.2.jar
    urls[18] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/hibernate3/maven-hibernate3-jdk15/2.2/maven-hibernate3-jdk15-2.2.jar
    urls[19] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.4.0.GA/hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar
    urls[20] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/ejb3-persistence/1.0.2.GA/ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar
    urls[21] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations/3.1.0.GA/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.1.0.GA.jar
    urls[22] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.4.0.GA/hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar
    urls[23] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar
    urls[24] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/javassist/javassist/3.4.GA/javassist-3.4.GA.jar
    urls[25] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/jboss/jboss-common/4.0.2/jboss-common-4.0.2.jar
    urls[26] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/slide/webdavlib/2.0/webdavlib-2.0.jar
    urls[27] = file:/d:/Settings/U190552/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.6.2/xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar
    [FATAL ERROR] Container realm = plexus.core
    urls[0] = file:/D:/DEV/TOOLS/apache-maven-2.2.1/lib/maven-2.2.1-uber.jar
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] FATAL ERROR
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] javax/mail/internet/AddressException
    javax.mail.internet.AddressException
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Trace
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/AddressException
     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
     at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:174)
     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:150)
     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:163)
     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:425)
     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:394)
     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:829)
     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:712)
     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:618)
     at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:470)
     at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:122)
     at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:209)
     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:221)
     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:151)
     at org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.configuration.AnnotationComponentConfiguration.createConfiguration(AnnotationComponentConfiguration.java:93)
     at org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.configuration.AbstractComponentConfiguration.getConfiguration(AbstractComponentConfiguration.java:51)
     at org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.exporter.Hbm2DDLExporterMojo.doExecute(Hbm2DDLExporterMojo.java:87)
     at org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.HibernateExporterMojo.execute(HibernateExporterMojo.java:152)
     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
     at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:115)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.internet.AddressException
     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
     at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
     at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
     at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:274)
     at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClass(RealmClassLoader.java:214)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
     ... 47 more
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
    [INFO] Finished at: Fri Dec 31 11:42:20 CET 2010
    [INFO] Final Memory: 10M/24M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

log4j.xml

```
    <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

        <appender name="email" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
            <param name="Threshold" value="error" />
            <param name="BufferSize" value="10" />
            <param name="SMTPHost" value="smtp.host" />
            <param name="From" value="site@domain.com" />
            <param name="To" value="CDB@mail" />
            <param name="Subject" value="[Site] Error - TST" />
            <param name="LocationInfo" value="false" />
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout">
                <param name="LocationInfo" value="false" />
            </layout>
        </appender>

        <root>
            <priority value="DEBUG" />
            <appender-ref ref="email" />
        </root>

    </log4j:configuration>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>Mail-logging-and-hbm2ddl</groupId>
<artifactId>Mail-logging-and-hbm2ddl</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>3.8.1</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
<version>3.2.6.ga</version>
<exclusions>
<!-- We need a higher version of ehcache -->
<exclusion>
 <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
 <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
<version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
<version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
<version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>
 </dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources-${targetprofile}</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
<configuration>
 <source>${javaVersion}</source>
 <target>${javaVersion}</target>
 <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<executions>
 <execution>
  <phase>process-classes</phase>
  <goals>
   <goal>hbm2ddl</goal>
  </goals>
 </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
 <componentProperties>
  <propertyfile>
   src/main/resources-${targetprofile}/configuration.properties
  </propertyfile>
  <export>false</export>
  <drop>true</drop>
  <outputfilename>
   ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-schema.sql
  </outputfilename>
 </componentProperties>
</configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
<javaVersion>1.6</javaVersion>
</properties>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

This other question gave me the answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2831474/559203)
So the anwser is to add the javax.mail dependency to the plugin as follows :

```
<build>
....

<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>hbm2ddl</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <componentProperties>
                    <propertyfile>
                        src/main/resources-${targetprofile}/configuration.properties
                    </propertyfile>
                    <export>false</export>
                    <drop>true</drop>
                    <outputfilename>
                        ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-schema.sql
                    </outputfilename>
                </componentProperties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message as well as the debug log, it appears that `javax.mail` dependency is not part of the dependencies that are present when `hbm2ddl` is run.  Since the contents above are poorly formatted and possibly incomplete, it is difficult to say why.  One possibility is `javax.mail` dependency is not included. Or if yes, included with incorrect (say `runtime`) scope.

You could try running the goal removing the `SMTPAppender` from `log4j.xml` to see if it works.  This will help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thans for the quick reply. Indeed, checked the formatting, should look better now. Dependency to javax.mail is included in pom, default scope (so its compile-time). If I remove <appender-ref ref="email"> all is well but I need it